# How can I create a Gantt diagram with phpSpreadSheet?

Tags: php, excel, xlsx, gantt-chart, phpspreadsheet

I am using phpSpreadSheet to create a Gantt diagram from a template, but when I complete the template using this library the diagram appears empty. But if I complete the template manually, the diagram appears completed. I have downloaded the template from [here](https://templates.office.com/es-es/planificador-de-proyectos-de-gantt-tm02887601)

This is my code:

```
//For documentation creation
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

//Excel
$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = 'files/Cronograma.xlsx';

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  * */
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  * */
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);


$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();


$sheet->setCellValue('C5', 1);
$sheet->setCellValue('D5', 5);
$sheet->setCellValue('E5', 1);
$sheet->setCellValue('F5', 5);


$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$excelName = 'test.xlsx';
$writer->save($excelName);
```

Data manually introduced:

[image: Data manually introduced]

Data introduced by code:

[image: Data introduced by code]

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of the excel features aren't implemented (e.g. format as table, pivot tables). 
It would not be so pretty, but you can color single cells/ cellranges in a specific color like

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3:B7')->getFill()
->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
```

for more information take a look to [enter link description here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that´s not what I´m looking for. I want the xlsx file to complete the diagram automatically, not by my php code. With php code I only want to fill the cell from C to G